# UIToolbar doesn't show UIBarButtonItem with custom view (only below iOS 11)

Tags: ios9, ios10, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, custom-view

I'm testing a simple `UIToolbar`, with two `UIBarButtonItem` as items, one built using `initWithCustomView:` method, the other one using `initWithTitle:style:target:action:` method.

The second button cand be viewed on the toolbar, but the first one is missing.

**The problem occurs only on iOS 9 and iOS 10. It doesn't occur on iOS 11.**

Does anyone have any idea?

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[toolbar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"one" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:audioOnIcon] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button],
                   [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil],
                   nil]];

[toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[toolbar setShadowImage:[UIImage new] forToolbarPosition:UIBarPositionAny];
toolbar.accessibilityIdentifier = toolbarIdentifier;

[self.view insertSubview:toolbar atIndex:[self getSubviewIndex:toolbar.accessibilityIdentifier]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[subview]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:@{ @"subview": toolbar}]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[subview]-padding-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:@{ @"padding": @(2 * PADDING) } views:@{ @"subview": toolbar }]];
```

[image: screenshot from iPad 2]

Comment: Can we see your code please?

Comment: sorry, forgot about the code. you can see it now

Comment: Solved it by setting [button sizeToFit];

Comment: Please mark the "sizeToFit" solution as correct answer then. I can confirm this worked (on iOS 10, same issue).

Answer (score 7):

You need to call the `sizeToFit` method on your `UIButton` before adding it to toolbar.

Something like this:
`[button sizeToFit]; // (Objective-C)`
OR
`button.sizeToFit() // (Swift)`

Although its to late to answer to this question, but hope this helps you or someone else.